# Strange after_create behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some rails Model `Parent` that has_many `Child`, and I have this `after_create` callback in Parent class

```
has_many :children
after_create :add_children

def add_children
 self.childlren = fetch_some_children
end
```

However, this doesn't do anything and the children fetched from `fetch_some_children` didn't update their foreign keys. Now if I changed the callback to be `before_create` instead of `after_create`, then it works and children foreign keys are updated, so why does this happen?

**Edit:**
I had some other complex piece of code that resulted in this problem, so it's now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
def add_children
 self.childlren = fetch_some_children
 self.save # to persist the data
end
```

When you use `before_create` it sets `children` and it gets saved, `after_create` as it said it is already created, you have to persist your data

Comment: Well, assigning collection to has_many field doesn't need updating the object again, it was another problem that I solved now, thanks anyway :)